# Reasoning - Seating Arrangement

Tags: puzzle

Eight fiends P, Q, R, S, T, V, W and Y are sitting around a square table in such a way that four of them sit at four corners of the square while the rest sit in the middle of each of the four sides. The one who sit at the four corners face the centre while those who sit in the middle of the sides, face outside.

- S sits third to the right of P.
- P faces the centre.
- Y is not an immediate neighbor of P or S.
- T sits third to the right of R.
- R does not sit in the middle of any of the sides and also R is not an immediate neighbor of Y.
- Only one person sits between P and V.
- Q is not an immediate neighbor of V.

After getting the places of P and S there can be multiples places for Y, R. How do we solve these kind of problems quickly?

Comment: Eight fiends is a nice touch

Comment: Draw a picture?

Comment: Already did, you get stuck eventually.

Comment: I think the key is v actually. V needs to sit two away from p. But r is at a corner, and there's two choices. But one forces y to be at the other corner, and that can't work as then there's no place for v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number the seats 1 through 8 clockwise, with the odd seats being the corners.  We might as well put P at 1.   Then S is in 6 and Y can only go in 3 or 4.  Assuming Y is in 4, R must go in 7 and T conflicts with Y, so Y is in 3.  V must then go in 7, R in 5, T in 2, Q in 4, W in 8.  So the order around the table is PTYQRSVU

Comment: How does T conflict with Y? If R goes at 3, then T sits third to the right of R i.e at 8.

Comment: I got my right and left backwards.  To the right for somebody who is at a corner is counterclockwise.  It just reversed the answer.  Fixed.

Comment: awesome, even I had it wrong direction wise. Thanks!